# Get js value and display on visualfoce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I want to pass the value I got at js to apex.

I was able to obtain the record ID obtained on the object details page with visualforce.

I want to pass the acquired value to the controller and display it as the initial display on the visualforce page.

However, I understand how to press the button to pass to apex,   but I can not pass it to apex when loading the page without pressing the button.

What should I do?

＝＝
Apex

```
public class SampleController {

    public string ctlpara{get;set;}

    public string aaa{get;set;}

    public string ccc{get;set;}

    public PageReference pageRef{get;set;}

    

    //コンストラクタ

    public SampleController(){

        this.aaa='ここに値を入れる';

        this.ctlpara = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('thisparam');

        this.ccc=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('actprm');

    }

    

    public void init(){

        this.bbb=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('actprm');

    }

    

    public pagereference ctlfunc(){

        ctlpara = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('actprm');

        return null;

    }

}
```

＝＝
Visualforce

```
<apex:page controller="SampleController" id="page" action="{!init}">

    

        <apex:pageBlock >

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="aaa">            

                <apex:form id="form">

                    <apex:inputText label="ここにjsの値を入れたい" value="{!aaa}" />

                    <apex:actionFunction name="actfunc" action="{!ctlfunc}" reRender="dummy">

                        <apex:param name="actprm" value="" />

                    </apex:actionFunction>

              <!--I want to display at this apex:OUTPUTLABEL -->      

                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!ccc}" />

                    

                </apex:form>

            </apex:pageBlockSection> 

        </apex:pageBlock>

    

    <script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = onLoad();

    

    function onLoad() {

    //I got the value    
        var sample = location.href;

        alert(sample);

        actfunc(sample);

    }

    </script>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not connected apex:param with any controller side variable.

```
<apex:param name="actprm" value="" />   ///Value parameter is not connected with any controller side variable.
<apex:param name="actprm" value="{!controllerVariable}" /> //This is correct.
```